# How set std::string type on lldb?

Tags: c++, string, debugging, lldb

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string name = "Foo";
    return 0;
}
```

When i will debug with `lldb` i want set a `std::string` like i set this `int`:

```
expr int $num = 4
```

I try:

`expr std::string $name = "Foo"`

And i got:

`error: no type named 'string' in namespace 'std'`

Does anyone understand what is going on? How can i create a `std::string` on `lldb`?

**Obs:**

When i print `name`, lldb give me this type `std::__1::string` for `std::string`:

```
p foo
(std::__1::string) $2 = "foo"
```

Comment: `std::string` is an alias for `std::basic_string<char>` so maybe that works?

Comment: @NikosC. Did not work, i got: `error: no template named 'basic_string' in namespace 'std'`

Comment: try to use what the name return to you... in your question `std::__1::string`

Comment: @ZigRazor I got: `error: no viable conversion from 'const char [5]' to 'std::__1::string'`

Comment: so try to use `const char *` or `const char[]` or `const char[5]`. Let me know if one of this works.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, I don't think you can modify classes in this way, only POD values

Comment: @ZigRazor when i try:  `expr const char * $foo`, `expr const char $foo[] ` and `expr const char $foo[4]` works fine, returning in every example a `const char *` type. Thanks.

Comment: so i trasform the comment in answer to get the question solved

Comment: done! just to approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternatively:

- `expr const char * $foo`
- `expr const char $foo[]`
- `expr const char $foo[4]`

Obviously the last one can be used only if you know the dimension of the char-array

Answer (score 6):

std::string looks simple from the outside but it's actually a quite complex little beast...

For instance, all the std::string constructors except the copy constructors take defaulted arguments (allocators and the like) that most normal C++ users never override, and so don't know about. Since we are getting our information about the type from the DWARF debug info, we are restricted by what it represents.  It doesn't represent the values of defaulted arguments, however, so we don't know how to fill them in.

You can try a little harder by reading the string header, and you figure out you need to provide a size and an allocator, and get to something like:

```
expr std::string $myStr("Foo", 4, std::allocator<char>())
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1EPKcmRKS4_
```

That fails because the allocator is everywhere inlined, so lldb can't find a constructor to call for it.

The real solution to this is to have lldb rebuild the std module from headers, import the resultant clang module into lldb's compiler and use that to create these values.  At that point we'd have the information needed to do this job.  For instance we would know about defaulted arguments, and could instantiate the missing allocator from the module.

But building a Clang Module from the c++ std headers turns out not to be entirely trivial, so we're still working on that...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of a compiler are you using? From what I found this issue exists with clang 5.0.1 but not with clang 7.0.0. It could be an issue linked to the address sanitizer.

Try `brew install llvm --with-toolchain --with-lldb`

Comment: `g++ -v` `Apple clang version 11.0.0`

Comment: Where are the `--with-toolchain` and `--with-lldb` flags documented?  Are there others?